# Signing in via Twitter OAuth doesn't remember authorization

Tags: java, oauth, twitter-oauth, spring-social

I am writing a web application and have just implemented that a user can sign in via Twitter, using spring-social-(core/twitter).

However, Twitter behaves strangely. After the initial authentication/authorization, every time I'm sending a user to Twitter for authentication, Twitter prompts to authorize my application again. I've looked into the connected Twitter profile. My app is there and authorized correctly (in my case for read access).

I don't have a case of requesting additional permissions. All my application needs is read access (the authorization dialog confirms this).

I am using the `OAuth1Operations` (returned by the `TwitterConnectionFactory`) to do the OAuth dance and save the resulting connection in a database. My front-end is written with Wicket 1.5.

I can work around this behavior by just re-authorizing my app again and again when I want to sign in via Twitter, but this is a big nuisance. Anyone knows what I'm missing here?

Here is my code:

```
TwitterConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (TwitterConnectionFactory) connectionFactoryLocator.getConnectionFactory(Twitter.class);
String callbackUrl = [...];

if (pageParameters.get("oauth_token").isNull() || pageParameters.get("oauth_verifier").isNull()) {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    params.add("x_auth_access_type", "read");
    OAuthToken token = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().fetchRequestToken(callbackUrl, params);

    String url = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().buildAuthorizeUrl(token.getValue(), OAuth1Parameters.NONE);

    getSession().setAttribute("twitter_token", token);
    setResponsePage(new RedirectPage(url));
} else {
    String token = pageParameters.get("oauth_token").toString();
    String verifier = pageParameters.get("oauth_verifier").toString();

    OAuthToken previousToken = (OAuthToken) getSession().getAttribute("twitter_token");

    if (previousToken.getValue().equals(token)) {
        AuthorizedRequestToken authorizedRequestToken = new AuthorizedRequestToken(previousToken, verifier);

        OAuthToken accessToken = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().exchangeForAccessToken(authorizedRequestToken, null);
        Connection<Twitter> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution! It is also detailed here: [Simple Twitter Oauth authorization asking for credentials every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578881/simple-twitter-oauth-authorization-asking-for-credentials-every-time)

The problem was that I specifically requested Twitter to authorize my app every time. Replacing:

```
String url = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().buildAuthorizeUrl(token.getValue(), OAuth1Parameters.NONE);
```

with

```
String url = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().buildAuthenticateUrl(token.getValue(), OAuth1Parameters.NONE);
```

solves the issue!
Calling the URL for authentication does only ask for authorization if the app hasn't been authorized yet.

Comment: I get the same problem, but I'm already calling `authenticate` instead of `authorize` :(

Comment: @Deejay: Can you post your code, please? Maybe you have encountered an other problem...

Comment: I figured it out - Twitter changed their API in the last year, so you have to tick a checkbox on their Application settings page in order to allow the OAuth connection to be used for authentication.

Comment: @Deejay Thank you, this was very helpful. It is the "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" checkbox on the settings tab of the application.